# How should I implement the cumulative distribution function of a discrete r.v that follows binomial distribution in R?

Tags: r, distributions, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

**Problem**

> Let there be a discrete random variable s.t.  $$X \sim
>  \text{Binom}(20,0.02)$$ and $X(\Omega) = \{0,1,2,\ldots,20\}$
>   Let there be also a constant $C$ s.t.  $$\Pr(X\leq\frac{120}{C})
>  > 0.99$$
>   *What is the maximum $C$ such that the above relation holds? And 
>   how should this problem be solved in R?*

**What has already been known**

```
pbinom(4, size=20, prob=0.02)
```

gives the probability that $X$ is less than 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the function qbinom? This gives the quantile of the binomial distribution.

We have that qbinom(0.99, size = 20, prob = 0.02) = 2, so 
$$ \mathbb{P}(X \leq 2) = 0.99. $$

So the maximum $C$ for which 
$$ \mathbb{P}\mathopen{}\left(X \leq \frac{120}{C}\right) = 0.99 $$
holds is $C=60$.